# rails: order query by big decimal attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, decimal

I've got an active record model with an attribute of big decimal type. I wanted to be able to order with respect to this attribute being treated as a number. Instead I've got the following:

```
1.9.1 :034 > y Ball.order("radius desc").map{|b| b.radius}
  Ball Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `balls`.* FROM `balls` ORDER BY radius desc
---
- 11.5
- 8.0
- 4.9
- 12.0
- 6.6
- 6.8
- 10.0
- 6.0
- 7.6
- 8.4
```

I'm wondering whether in **rails** there is a reasonable possibility to perform ordering without introducing considerable changes in to the query.

Comment: what have you set the `radius` field type to be?

Comment: it is of decimal type

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, ruby-2.0.0-p0, 'rails', '3.2.13', and discount is decimal, :precision => 8,  :scale => 2, :default => 0.0

```
y Project.order("discount desc").map{|p| p.discount }
Project Load (2.4ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` ORDER BY discount desc
---
- 35.3
- 5.3
- 2.9
- 2.3
- 0.0
```

Comment: My versions are: ruby 1.9.3p392, Rails 3.2.13.